# Vue: whitespace when carousel is sliding

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I've encountered a problem when I want to create a carousel using VueJs. my problem is, there seems to be whitespace when the slider is running. When one image went to other images, there seems to be whitespace in an instant that fade after one second.

here's my code :

```
Vue.component('kangaroo-slider', {
  template: `
    <div id="carousel">

        <div class="carousel__inner" >
          <div class="carousel__item">
            <a href="#">
              <transition tag="div" :name="transitionName">
                <img :src="image[current]" class="carousel__image" :key="current">
              </transition>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>


    </div>
  `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      image: [
        'https://www.pocarisweat.id//assets/uploads/2019/09/54ad7ba3a1892e0bcc365d021507b713.png',
        'https://www.pocarisweat.id//assets/uploads/2019/08/09b43d7b3fb60d5acf782f9510cb87a0.jpg',
        'https://www.pocarisweat.id//assets/uploads/2019/08/00a75c18203defa69bc8ad7aace5f60b.jpg'
      ],
      current: 0,
      show: false,
      transitionName: 'fade',
      show: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    slide() {
      let maxSlide = this.image.length
      setInterval(() => {
        if (this.current < maxSlide - 1) {
          this.transitionName = 'slide-next'
          this.current++
        } else {
          this.transitionName = 'slide-prev'
          this.current = 0
        }

      }, 2000)

    }
  },
  created () {
    this.slide()
  },
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

you can see how it works here: https://codepen.io/learningfrontendweb/pen/ZEEvRRZ

Comment: Not sure exactly how to fix it but the reason you're getting the whitespace is because there isn't anything to say where the next image should slide in from. The next image is effectively sliding in from its default position which is to already be on screen i.e translate(0px) . But since the previous image is still sliding out and taking up that space, it has to wait for that transition to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make some changes in your css file

```
.carousel__inner {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
}

.carousel__image {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Anyway here is the link where I've fixed it:

https://codepen.io/Nevados/pen/mddXWYy